# how to make div fade/grey. Opacity works but makes it transperant

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two div connected to each other through svg line(implementation from d3js chart). On certain action, I want to fade/greyout some of the divs. I am able to achieve it by setting opacity 0.5. But it makes the div transparent so background svg line gets visible. I have created a jsfiddle to demo the issue.

```
<div id="div1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top:0; left:0; background:#777; position:absolute;">
    <div class="child1">
    text
  </div>
    <div class="child2">
  
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top:200px; left:200px; background:#333; position:absolute;">
    <div class="child1">
    text
  </div>
    <div class="child2">
  
  </div>
</div>

<svg width="300" height="250"><line x1="50" y1="50" x2="350" y2="350" stroke="black"/></svg>
<button onclick="fade()">
fade
</button>
<button onclick="reset()">
reset
</button>


function fade () {
 document.getElementById('div1').className = 'greyout';
}

.greyout {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/srxoL1zj/2/)

Is there any way to hide line inside div when opacity is set to 0.5?

mock screen(requirement):

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use a grey color instead of opacity?

Comment: in real scenario, I have multiple divs with diff color. and each div has three section with diff color for header, body and footer. Opacity setting makes whole div (of any color) fade. I can achieve similar with changing color but it is little tricky in my d3 chart.

Comment: What exactly do you want this to look like?  It isn't clear from your description.  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Use hsl colors instead, where you can change "s" and "l" when fading out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here is a solution that allows you to keep the logic with the opacity, but with a slight change to the structure of html elements.

I have just added a wrapper div around the "cards" (`div1` and `div2`) and moved all inline styles to it except the `background` property, then gave the wrapper a new `background: white;` (you can give it any color you like).

The idea is that the outer wrapper doesn't recieve any opacity and stays opaque, but the inner "card" `div1` / `div2` can recieve the opacity you want without any other elements showing through:

```js
function fade() {
  document.getElementById('div1').className = 'greyout';
}

function reset() {
  document.getElementById('div1').className = 'reset';
}
```

```css
.greyout {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.reset {
  opacity: 1;
}

.child1 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #3690e7;
}

.child2 {
  height: 75px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top:0; left:0; position:absolute; background: white;">
  <div id="div1" style="background:#777;">
    <div class="child1">
      text
    </div>
    <div class="child2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top:200px; left:200px; position:absolute; background: white;">
  <div id="div2" style="background:#333;">
    <div class="child1">
      text
    </div>
    <div class="child2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<svg width="300" height="250"><line x1="50" y1="50" x2="350" y2="350" stroke="black"/></svg>
<button onclick="fade()">
  fade
</button>
<button onclick="reset()">
  reset
</button>
```

Comment: thanks! this is the perfect solution!! before posting the que, I tried this approach to add wrapper div. but I did not give background color so it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
.greyout {
  filter: grayscale(70%);
}
```

Or another percentage depending on you taste.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it. but it is not giving similar fade look.